# Recurence $(1+3^{n+1})x_n - 3^n x_{n-1} - 2\cdot 3^n x_{n+1} = y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, lp-spaces

Let $(y_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $l^1$, that is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n| < +\infty.
$$
Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers, where
$$
x_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \qquad x_2 = \frac{7x_1 - y_1}{6}
$$
and
$$
(1+3^{n+1})x_n - 3^n x_{n-1} - 2\cdot 3^n x_{n+1} = y_n, \quad n \ge 2.
$$

Hence, given $(y_n)_{n\ge 1}$, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is determined uniquely by its value $x_1$.

> Does there exsits $x_1$ such that $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is in $l^1$?

I tried to do some numerical analysis, and for
$$
y_n = \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
I suspect that the answer is *yes*, and $x_1 \sim 0.2496721891826\dots$.

Comment: Why do you think that?